# Download pdf from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to download PDFs from several websites. I cant manage to successfully download them from any URL.

```
        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {

                byte[] filedata = client.DownloadData(url);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(filedata))
                {

                }
            }

        }
```

I googled a lot and most post referenced some kind of SSL problem. I added SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ( and tried with ssl3). Most of these websites are well known websites (ex: dropbox). 
I tried using `HttpClient` as well. 
I tried using `DownloadFile` as well.

The exception I get is the following:

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 1/2
>
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 2/2
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>       System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[], int, int, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
>       System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[], int, int)

Is it possible the problem is because of the size? Most of them weight between 5mb and 20 mb.

UPDATE:

Using the code in a console app will download files correctly. Could this be a problem with iis?

Comment: You might be getting rate-limited. Are you making a lot of these requests in a short time frame?  I see you have a `for` loop...

Comment: I suppose they have bot control. Use dcsoup library instead.  https://github.com/matarillo/dcsoup  And pretend like you are connecting as chrome user

Comment: I could not even download a file once. ill try with dcsoup